# Using layout_above/layout_below does not yield expected results. Item dissapears

Tags: android, xml, image, android-relativelayout

I have the following code:

grid_view_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.entu.artapp.utils.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/gridItem_squareImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <com.entu.artapp.utils.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/gridItem_selectedColor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="#e85349"
        android:alpha="0.45"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <com.entu.artapp.utils.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/gridItem_constantGrey"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:alpha="0.45"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/gridItem_textView"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:hint="AAAAAAAAA"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/checkmark"
        android:id="@+id/gridItem_selectedCheckMark"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/gridItem_progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Which yields this view:

[image]

I want my item to look like this:

[image]

So, I added this line in my CheckMark imageView code:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/"gridItem_progressBar"
```

And the checkMark imageview just dissapears. Same for layout_below, as shown here:

[image]

Can anyone help me in solving this problem?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It may help you if you use padding instead of above or below, why do you want linear layout as your parent and relative view as child it will be more easier if you have relative layout as parent. Hope this may help you.